# netbeans web application error 404 include a js

Tags: javascript, netbeans, get, http-status-code-404

I work with Netbeans 8.2 and I created a Web Application. I have a html and a js.
The html is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The project's structure is

[image]

I want to include the js1.js.

When I run the application in the browser's console I get a 404

```
GET http://localhost:8080/Prueba/js1.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]
```

Why do I get this 404?

Answer (score 0):

file **js1.js** has to be inside the **web** directory(in netbeans) and not outside as you show in the image